# VBA - Create array of unique values and sum corresponding values

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Im looking for some help with a VBA problem I'm having. Basically, I'm collecting information from a source file on sheet1 into static arrays. From those static arrays I'm creating a dynamic array with account numbers, and a calculated value. What I'm trying to do next is create a second dynamic array with only unique account numbers and summing the calculated values in the previous dynamic array. But I have no idea how to do that...

The following is what I have so far.

```
   Dim ClosingCash() As Variant, MarginExcess() As Variant, VarMarg() As Variant, Acct() As Variant, FX() As Variant, UniqueAcct() As Variant, Answers() As Variant
 Dim Dim1 As Long, Counter As Long, W_Sum As Long

Sheet1.Activate

Acct = Range("b2", Range("b2").End(xlDown))
ClosingCash = Range("f2", Range("f2").End(xlDown))
MarginExcess = Range("j2", Range("J2").End(xlDown))
FX = Range("n2", Range("n2").End(xlDown))
VarMarg = Range("o2", Range("o2").End(xlDown))

Dim1 = UBound(ClosingCash, 1)

ReDim Answers(1 To Dim1, 1 To 2)

For Counter = 1 To Dim1
    Answers(Counter, 1) = Acct(Counter, 1)
    Answers(Counter, 2) = (WorksheetFunction.Min(ClosingCash(Counter, 1) + VarMarg(Counter, 1), MarginExcess(Counter, 1)) * FX(Counter, 1))
Next Counter

Sheet3.Activate
Range("a2", Range("a2").Offset(Dim1 - 1, 1)).Value = Answers
```

What I would like to print out are the unique account numbers, and the sum of Answers(counter, 2) that correspond to that account number, similar to a SumIf.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

### Sum Unique

- In your code you could use it like this:

  ```
  Dim Data As Variant: Data = getUniqueSum(Answers)
  If Not IsEmpty(Data) Then       
      Sheet3.Range("E2").Resize(UBound(Data, 1), UBound(Data, 2)).Value = Data
  End If
  ```

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Writes the unique values from the first column of a 2D array
'               and the sum of the corresponding values in its second column,
'               to a 2D one-based two-columns array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function getUniqueSum( _
    Data As Variant) _
As Variant
    If IsEmpty(Data) Then Exit Function
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        Dim Key As Variant
        Dim i As Long
        Dim c1 As Long: c1 = LBound(Data, 2)
        Dim c2 As Long: c2 = c1 + 1
        For i = LBound(Data, 1) To UBound(Data, 1)
            Key = Data(i, c1)
            If Not IsError(Key) Then
                If Len(Key) > 0 Then
                    .Item(Key) = .Item(Key) + Data(i, c2)
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        If .Count = 0 Then Exit Function
        Dim Result As Variant: ReDim Result(1 To .Count, 1 To 2)
        i = 0
        For Each Key In .Keys
            i = i + 1
            Result(i, 1) = Key
            Result(i, 2) = .Item(Key)
        Next Key
        getUniqueSum = Result
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: This worked! I have no idea how, but ill be spending a bunch of time figuring it out. Thank you!

Comment: I've spent some time with this and it works great. But I've run into a new issue and I'm unsure of how to proceed. Each Key corresponds to a certain account #, but there is more than 1 data series or array i would like to sum. Is it possible to have multiple items for each key? If not, is it possible to keep the key's the same, assign new items and sum those, then somehow print them out in a column beside the original items?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
Sub GetUniqueSum()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim numRows As Long, endRow As Long, outputRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim rangeText As String
    Dim acct As Variant
    Dim Sum As Double, ClosingCash As Double, MarginExcess As Double
    Dim FX As Double, VarMarg As Double
    Dim Value As Double, Value2 As Double
    
    'Get the last row as a string
    numRows = Range("B2", Range("b2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    endRow = CStr(numRows + 1)
    rangeText = "B2:O" & endRow
    
    'Sort the range
    Set Rng = Range("Sheet2!" & rangeText)
    Rng.Sort (Rng.Columns(1))
    
    'Initialize variables
    acct = Rng.Cells(2, 1)
    outputRow = 1
    Sum = 0
    
    'Calculate Sums
    For i = 1 To Rng.Rows.Count
        If Rng.Cells(i, 1) <> acct Then
            'No longer same acct, print out results
            outputRow = outputRow + 1
            Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(outputRow, 1) = acct
            Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(outputRow, 2) = Sum
            acct = Rng.Cells(i, 1)
            Sum = 0
        End If
        ClosingCash = Rng(i, 5).Value
        MarginExcess = Rng(i, 9).Value
        FX = Rng(i, 13).Value
        VarMarg = Rng(i, 14).Value
        Value = ClosingCash + VarMarg
        Value2 = MarginExcess * FX
        If Value > Value2 Then Value = Value2
        Sum = Sum + Value
    Next
    'Print out last result
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(outputRow + 1, 1) = acct
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(outputRow + 1, 2) = Sum
End Sub
```